# How to search Google News archives?

Tags: google-news

How do I search for a specific newspaper for archived articles? Google has eliminated 'advanced search' as an option.

The link once was:

```
https://news.google.com/archivesearch/advanced_search
```

This is the paper I'd like to search:

```
https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=ZuSUVyMx-TgC
```

I've tried a Google search using:

```
courthouse source:"reading eagle" site:https://news.google.com/newspapers
```

Which has zero results.

Answer (score 1):

**instead of:**

```
courthouse source:"reading eagle" site:https://news.google.com/newspapers
```

search for:

```
courthouse source:readingeagle site:https://news.google.com/newspapers
```

or:

```
courthouse source:reading eagle site:https://news.google.com/newspapers
```

Comment: Thanks... that seems to help... although it only finds one or two instances of very common words. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @TedScheckler its because those pages are not ocr-ed & indexed

Comment: But... "militants say trials certain" source:reading eagle site:https://news.google.com/newspapers gives me zero results... "militants say trials certain" site:news.google.com/newspapers gives me one result with that Reading Eagle source. I think they are ocr'ed but specifying the source is hit-or-miss.

Comment: @TedScheckler google search engine works upon let's call it "weird" logic sometimes... indexing of the results you see its often forgotten and ppl expect google to work as human would... see here my answer from another post if you care: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118953/