# How can I merge multiple Google searches

Tags: google-search

How can I combine all of these searches into one and get all the results from one search?

Search 01: `[keyword] site:docs.google.com/document/d`
Search 02: `[keyword] -inurl:(htm|html|php|pls|txt) intitle:index.of “last modified” (mp3|mp4|pdf)`
Search 03: `[keyword] parent directory`

For example, I have tried something like this. But, it seems to be not working.

```
[keyword] (site:docs.google.com/document/d OR -inurl:(htm|html|php|pls|txt) intitle:index.of “last modified” (mp3|mp4|pdf) OR parent directory)
```

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Okay. Maybe I'm not explaining this correctly. Sorry about that. The combined query (final query) should give more results than 1st, 2nd and 3rd queries since it's combined using **OR** operator. But I'm getting way fewer results.

Comment: _The query result should be like this..._
`"ABC" - About 631,000,000 results` [link](https://www.google.com/search?q="ABC")  
`"XYZ" - About 354,000,000 results` [link](https://www.google.com/search?q="XYZ")  
`"ABC" OR "XYZ" - About 1,130,000,000 results` [link](https://www.google.com/search?q="ABC"+OR+"XYZ")

Comment: _What I'm getting_
`1st Query: About 10,800 results` [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Avengers+site%3Adocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fd)
`2nd Query: About 10,500 results` [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Avengers+-inurl%3A(htm%7Chtml%7Cphp%7Cpls%7Ctxt)+intitle%3Aindex.of+“last+modified”+(mp3%7Cmp4%7Cpdf))
`3rd Query: About 83 results` [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Avengers+(site%3Adocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fd+OR+-inurl%3A(htm%7Chtml%7Cphp%7Cpls%7Ctxt)+intitle%3Aindex.of+“last+modified”+(mp3%7Cmp4%7Cpdf)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the general rule of searching is:
 **more you add to your search query - the fewer results you will get**

your (**`About 14,700 results`**):

```
[keyword] (site:docs.google.com/document/d 
       OR intitle:index.of “last modified” (mp3|mp4|pdf)
          -inurl:(htm|html|php|pls|txt) 
       OR parent directory)
```

is the same as (**`About 14,700 results`**):

```
keyword site:docs.google.com/document/d
     OR intitle:index.of "last modified" (mp3|mp4|pdf)
        -inurl:(htm|html|php|pls|txt) 
     OR parent directory
```

but you can try (**`About 11,700 results`**):

```
"keyword" site:docs.google.com/document/d
       OR intitle:index.of "last modified" (mp3|mp4|pdf)
          -inurl:(htm|html|php|pls|txt) 
       OR parent directory
```

Comment: Since I'm using **OR** operator, I should get at least about 14,700 results, right?

Comment: @DT yeah, theoretical 14,700 results

Comment: This is my attempt. Query 01: [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Avengers+site%3Adocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fd) Query 02: [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Avengers+-inurl%3A(htm%7Chtml%7Cphp%7Cpls%7Ctxt)+intitle%3Aindex.of+“last+modified”+(mp3%7Cmp4%7Cpdf)) Final Query: [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=Avengers+(site%3Adocs.google.com%2Fdocument%2Fd+OR+-inurl%3A(htm%7Chtml%7Cphp%7Cpls%7Ctxt)+intitle%3Aindex.of+“last+modified”+(mp3%7Cmp4%7Cpdf)))
This means the way we combined the query is wrong, right?

Comment: @DT no, the combination is right. the thing is that you expect that OR operator will give you the sum of 3 separate results, however thats not gona happen because google search engine works on different logic and those "14,700 results" are false or theoretical. in fact you cant get more than 500 results for any type of search query you try even if it shows you "you got 10,000,000 results"

Comment: @DT here you can read how google search logic works: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118953/get-all-image-search-results/118956#118956