# Only include search results that must exclude multiple words

Tags: google-search

Consider this search:

`rick's haven -bbq -barbeque -menu`

I am trying to find all results related to `Rick's Haven` as it relates to the movie `Bird Box`. However, there is a really famous BBQ restaurant that is also named "Rick's Haven".

How do I remove unrelated results? 
The search above would still include results about BBQ.

Answer (score -1):

if you are after the movie reference the best way is to:

- ```
  "rick's haven" "bird box"
  ```

Comment: Thank you. But is there an answer to the question of searching with the exclusion of multiple terms?

Comment: @hyang123 `"rick's haven" -restaurant -grill -bbq -barbeque -menu` you can add as many as you want, but note that more you add you will get less relevant results and most likely you shall not find what you are looking for. you can read more about how search engine logic works [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118953/get-all-image-search-results)